# Database access error during magento2 installtion

Tags: magento2

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and installed a fresh instance of Mysql.

During the installation, i have kept the root users password as blank.

During Magento 2 installation, I get access denied for the root user.

I tried without the password and by setting a new password.

I get as below:

There is no env.php in `app/etc` folder at this position.

[image]

Comment: login to phpmyadmin and check uername and password is correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mysql permission error try this

**Enter into mysql console**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

after that give permission to access

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento2.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON magento2.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**You can test like**

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

if it is allow to **mysql** console, your problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this file env.php from app/etc folder.

After that clear your browser cache and start again, It will resolve your issue.

Comment: no i dont ve env file as of now during the installation.